# Add values in x column where value in y column is equal to z

Tags: excel

I want to be able to  add up all values in x column (sales) where the value in column y (business name) is equal to z (Google)

Is this possible and how do you do it?

Comment: I think you can use [IIF](http://excelhelp.com/vba-programming/excel-iif-function) for this, but I don't use Excel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) function does exactly what you need:

```
=SUMIF(Y:Y,"=google",X:X)
```